# Pig SUBSTRING Function Not Generating a Column

Tags: foreach, substring, apache-pig

I am using a complex foreach statement to generate my data.
This is a sample row:

(2013-07-01)

Below is my code:

```
    joined_data = foreach old_data {

       date = old_data::date;
       month = SUBSTRING(date, 5, 7);

generate date, month;
};
```

When I go ahead and use the table, I get the following error:

```
<file script.pig, line 24, column 66> Invalid field projection. Projected field [month] does not exist in schema: old_data::date:chararray,:chararray.
```

Why doesn't month have a name?
I clearly named it.

When I write:

```
   joined_data = foreach data {

       date = old_data::date;
       month = SUBSTRING(date, 5, 7);

  generate date, $1;
  };
```

The code never finishes running (it cannot finish the reduce stage).

Any idea why this is happening and how I can make sure that Pig picks up on the name I gave to the month column?

Thanks.

Comment: I found a silly workaround:
generate date, month as month;

Comment: It's not a silly workaround, assigning it to "month" doesn't tell pig anything about the schema

Answer (score 0):

Indeep you can force the labelling with the AS month, but it doesn't explain why the $1 doesn't work :S

I would recommend you to use the `EXTRACT` with the appropriate regex and try a `DESCRIBE joined_data;` and `DESCRIBE old_data;` in order to see the labelling process :)